# How do I make view section scrollable?

Tags: views

I created a most read section with 4 articles in views.

The height is over. How do I make this section scrollable?

Is there any scrollbar settings in views?

[image]

Comment: You can easily achieve this through CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#(block-id-here){
  height:200px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Thanks, Smalution.

I had found out the solution for this.